# NSData missing after sent to other device

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdata, send

Data lost when transferring between devices. Doubt it really is lost - **I am sure I am doing something wrong - but what?!**

4 stepped approach. First 3 steps work like a charm, and I am able to verify the data can be parsed (before sending it). **I receive the data, but not all of it? When parsing it I can confirm the data type, but not the category information** (Gender, Category, SubCategory) - why? The steps:

1. Generate and store data (locally)
2. Verify data is stored correctly
3. Send data to another device (iPhone)
4. Receive data and Parse information --> UNSUCCESSFUL

**1. GENERATE DATA**

```
func selectCategories(){
    //Fixed data for testing
    let gender = "Women"
    let category = "Shoes"
    let subCategory = "Pumps"

    print("SENDING - Gender: \(gender), Category: \(category), SubCategory: \(subCategory)")

    sendCategories(gender, category: category, subCategory: subCategory)

}
```

**2. VERIFY DATA STORED**

```
func sendCategories(gender: String, category: String, subCategory: String){
    var messageCategory = MessageCategory(message: Message(messageType: MessageType.Category), gender: gender, category: category, subCategory: subCategory)
    let data = NSData(bytes: &messageCategory, length: sizeof(MessageCategory))
    print("SEND - LENGTH: \(data.length)")

    // VERIFY DATA STORED SUCCESFULLY (FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY)
    let messageCategoryFromData = UnsafePointer<MessageCategory>(data.bytes).memory
    if messageCategoryFromData.message.messageType == MessageType.Category{

    print("SENDING - Gender: \(messageCategoryFromData.gender), Category: \(messageCategoryFromData.category), SubCategory: \(messageCategoryFromData.subCategory)")

    let temp_gender = messageCategoryFromData.gender
    let temp_category = messageCategoryFromData.category
    let temp_subCategory = messageCategoryFromData.subCategory
    let message = messageCategoryFromData.message

    // SUCCESSFULLY PRINTS THE GENDER ETC WITH CORRECT INFORMATION -> DATA PARSING WORKS PRIOR TO SENDING DATA
    print("RECEIVED (PRIOR TO SENDING). Gender: \(temp_gender) Category: \(temp_category) SubCategory: \(temp_subCategory)")
    }
    else{
        print("WRONG MESSAGE TYPE")
    }

    // SEND THE DATA
    sendData(data)
}
```

**3. SEND DATA**

```
func sendData(data: NSData) {
    print("SENDING DATA")
    var sendDataError: NSError?
    let gameKitHelper = GameKitHelper.sharedInstance

    if let multiplayerMatch = gameKitHelper.multiplayerMatch {
        do {
            try multiplayerMatch.sendDataToAllPlayers(data, withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataMode.Reliable)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error while sending data: \(error)")
        } catch {
            print("Catch all errors: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

**4. RECEIVE DATA AND PARSE INFORMATION (ERROR)**

```
func matchReceivedData(match: GKMatch, data: NSData, fromPlayer player: String) {

    var message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory

    if message.messageType == MessageType.Category {

        let messageCategory = UnsafePointer<MessageCategory>(data.bytes).memory

        print("MESSAGE: \(messageCategory.message)")   <-- SUCCESSFUL
        print("DATA TYPE: \(messageCategory.message.messageType)")    <-- SUCCESSFUL
        print("RECEIVED - LENGTH: \(data.length)")        <-- SUCCESSFUL

        let gender = messageCategory.gender            <-- BECOMES NIL
        let category = messageCategory.category        <-- BECOMES NIL
        let subCategory = messageCategory.subCategory  <-- BECOMES NIL

        delegate?.setCategories(g, category: c, subCategory: s)

        print("RECEIVING - Gender: \(gender), Category: \(category), subCategory\(subCategory)")
    }
}
```

**Supporting structures**

```
enum MessageType: Int {
    case RandomNumber, Category, GameBegin, Move, LapComplete, GameOver
}

struct Message {
    let messageType: MessageType
}

struct MessageCategory {
    let message: Message
    let gender: String
    let category: String
    let subCategory: String
}
```

Comment: Try a change in step 4:
Remove `var message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory` and add there the line `let messageCategory = UnsafePointer<MessageCategory>(data.bytes).memory`. Also change the if to `if messageCategoryFromData.message.messageType == MessageType.Category`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @sunshine. But I need the first `var message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory` to test which type of data is received and thereafter parse it correctly. Any other ideas of what might disrupt the sending or receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I was using a `Struct` to handle the data. But after reading up I realize the struct is only pointing towards the data. This lead to that my `String` data was not sent with the NSData (`Float` and `Int` works fine).

Solution is to not use struct for handling object data but pass it as raw NSData and then always have a part of the data which is included which tells which type of data it is and then use the right parsing.

Answer (score 0):

i slightly modified you code

```
import XCPlayground
import Foundation

enum MessageType: Int {
    case RandomNumber, Category, GameBegin, Move, LapComplete, GameOver
}

struct Message {
    let messageType: MessageType
}

struct MessageCategory {
    let message: Message
    let gender: String
    let category: String
    let subCategory: String
}

func sendCategories(gender: String, category: String, subCategory: String)->NSData {
    var messageCategory = MessageCategory(message: Message(messageType: MessageType.Category), gender: gender, category: category, subCategory: subCategory)
    let data = NSData(bytes: &messageCategory, length: sizeof(MessageCategory))
    print("SEND - LENGTH: \(data.length)")

    // VERIFY DATA STORED SUCCESFULLY (FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY)
    let messageCategoryFromData = UnsafePointer<MessageCategory>(data.bytes).memory
    if messageCategoryFromData.message.messageType == MessageType.Category{

        print("SENDING - Gender: \(messageCategoryFromData.gender), Category: \(messageCategoryFromData.category), SubCategory: \(messageCategoryFromData.subCategory)")

        let temp_gender = messageCategoryFromData.gender
        let temp_category = messageCategoryFromData.category
        let temp_subCategory = messageCategoryFromData.subCategory
        let message = messageCategoryFromData.message

        // SUCCESSFULLY PRINTS THE GENDER ETC WITH CORRECT INFORMATION -> DATA PARSING WORKS PRIOR TO SENDING DATA
        print("RECEIVED (PRIOR TO SENDING). Gender: \(temp_gender) Category: \(temp_category) SubCategory: \(temp_subCategory)")
    }
    else{
        print("WRONG MESSAGE TYPE")
    }

    // SEND THE DATA
    //sendData(data)
    return data
}

let data = sendCategories("gender", category: "category", subCategory: "subcategory")

func matchReceivedData(data: NSData, fromPlayer player: String) {

    var message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory

    if message.messageType == MessageType.Category {

        let messageCategory = UnsafePointer<MessageCategory>(data.bytes).memory

        print("MESSAGE: \(messageCategory.message)")
        print("DATA TYPE: \(messageCategory.message.messageType)")
        print("RECEIVED - LENGTH: \(data.length)")

        let gender = messageCategory.gender
        let category = messageCategory.category
        let subCategory = messageCategory.subCategory


        print("RECEIVING - Gender: \(gender), Category: \(category), subCategory: \(subCategory)")
    }
}

matchReceivedData(data, fromPlayer: "player")

/*
SEND - LENGTH: 80
SENDING - Gender: gender, Category: category, SubCategory: subcategory
RECEIVED (PRIOR TO SENDING). Gender: gender Category: category SubCategory: subcategory
MESSAGE: Message(messageType: MessageType.Category)
DATA TYPE: Category
RECEIVED - LENGTH: 80
RECEIVING - Gender: gender, Category: category, subCategory: subcategory
*/
```

there is no 'sending' in my code. as you can see, the trouble is in you 'sending->receiving' part.

what is the match parameter for ? it is not used in your function ..

```
func matchReceivedData(match: GKMatch, data: NSData, fromPlayer player: String)
```

Comment: Thanks for the recoding. I too realized the error is somewhere in the sending or receiving part as my step 2 parses the information correctly. The 'match' is used in another part of the code which I did not show here to reduce clutter. Any idea what could be the issue with the sending or receiving?

Comment: step 4 above `matchReceivedData` covers the receiving part. Is a function part of `GameKit` which is automatically called on the other device when that device receives data during the game. As you can see the `if message.messageType == MessageType.Category` works. But the `let gender = messageCategory.gender` etc. becomes nil. Why that is - is beyond me at the moment :(

Comment: @PederWessel the only answer is that in you receiving data it is really nil. That is, why I send you an example with correct data.